# Some problems with a CSS and HTML accordion

Tags: html, css, accordion

I have begun writing a CSS and HTML collapsing menu system (AKA an accordion). I followed the tutorial posted [here](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/04/accordion-menu-css3-transition.html), however, I had to change it slightly. Instead of using `<a>` and `<p>` tags, I had to use `<div>` tags because I will be adding images to both 'sections' at a later stage. After I change the `<a>` and `<p>` tags to `<div>` tags, the slide-out content does not display when the mouse is hovering over the box. It is only when the mouse is moved away does the content briefly display before the 'drawer' retracts. I have posted my code bellow and any help would be very much appreciated.

Link to my CSS: http://cl.ly/Cuoe
Link to my HTML: http://cl.ly/Cuhf

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `#accordion div:hover` CSS rule is now catching both the `item` div AND the `itemTitle` and `itemContent` divs inside the item.

In your CSS file, try replacing both instances of `#accordion div:hover` with  `#accordion div.item:hover`. This will cause the rule to only apply to divs with class `item`.

**Edit:** You could also just change it to `#accordion .item:hover`

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ufPrF/

The problem was that you were setting a height property on `#accordion div:hover` which affected all `<div>s` inside the accordion (including title, content etc..). You should have either done `#accordion > div:hover` OR `#accordion .item:hover` (like in the fiddle)